# Serving html5 via nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, html, audio

I am using the  tag of html5 to playback an mp3. I am using Node to send the html as such:

```
 var http = require('http')
 var fs = require('fs')
 var html = fs.readFileSync(__dirname + '/some.html')
 http.createServer(function(req,res){
      res.writeHead(200, {"Content-Type" : "text/html"})
      res.write(html)
      res.end()
 }).listen(1337)
 console.log('Server is listening on 1337')
```

The some.html tag looks like this:

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
  <html>
  <body>
  <audio id="player" src="/Users/alex/yodog/DTSE9.mp3" controls>
  </audio>
  </body>
  </html>
```

I think I missing something BIG here, because when I open the same html file in the browser, everything works as expected. However, when I use node to deliver the html, nothing plays. The little audio control doesn't show the length of the audio track, and pressing play does nothing.

I think this part of a bigger issue regarding the implementation of html5. My server needs to do 'something' in order for html5 to work as expected. I've tried searching online and the only things that seem related to this is the Web Audio API. Or maybe I need to specify something in the response headers? Clearly I'm very confused here, and any pointers would appreciated.

Comment: When you open the file then `file:///Users/alex/yodog/DTSE9.mp3` is an absolute path on your filesystem and the mp3 is found there. After it's on a server the browser tries to get `http://localhost:1337/Users/alex/yodog/DTSE9.mp3` which probably doesn't exist. You should be able to see a 404 error in the developer tools' network tab.

Comment: Ok that makes sense. I investigated with developer tools, and the browser does indeed make another request for the mp3. However, given my basic server implementation, it receives a 200 OK. That is to be expected. I'm going to try modifying my server and then provide an update

Answer (score 0):

Ok so here is the updated code that fixes my problem. Basically, when node delivers the html to the client, the client makes another request for the audio. My server didn't accommodate this. Below is the updated server, and you will see that when the request asks for the audio, I send the audio.

```
 var http = require('http')
 var fs = require('fs')

 http.createServer(function(req,res){
     var url = req.url
     if(url === '/Users/alex/yodog/DTSE9.mp3')
     {
        res.writeHead(200, {"Content-Type" : "audio/mpeg"})
        var audio = fs.createReadStream(__dirname + '/DTSE9.mp3')
        audio.on('end', function(){
            console.log('no more audio')
            res.end()
        })
        audio.pipe(res)


     }
     else
     {
       res.writeHead(200, {"Content-Type" : "text/html"})
       var html = fs.createReadStream(__dirname + '/some.html')
       html.on('end', function(){
         console.log('no more html')
         res.end()
     })
     html.pipe(res)
   }

}).listen(1337)
console.log('Server is listening on 1337')
```